# Отправка данных с сервера на клиенты

Tags: c#, сокет, tcp

Имеется `TCP` сервер, задача которого  состоит в том, чтобы отсылать данные от оборудования клиентам (30 пакетов в секунду). 
*Вопрос:* как реализовать подключение новых клиентов, которым сразу начнут отсылать данные? 
*Идея:* при каждом новом подключении в список добавлять нового клиента и соответственно отправлять каждому последовательно - будет логично или можно как-то оптимальнее?

---

**P.S.** Код не требуется, интересует только как лучше поступить

Comment: Рез речь про TCP, то да, это единственный путь. Был бы UDP и были бы клиенты как то сгруппированы в отдельных физических подсетях можно было бы подумать о multicast или broadcast рассылках.

Comment: @Mike все клиенты находятся в локалке. То есть логичнее сделать по UDP протоколу, и отправлять мультикаст?

Comment: С мультикстом возни боюсь много. А броадкаст элементарно делается, просто широковещательный адрес вашей подсети указываете в качестве ip назначения и все. Ну может еще SO_BROADCAST на сокет поставить. Но надо не забывать, что у UDP нет гарантии доставки. Хотя и потери в пределах локалки маловероятны, но все таки при большой загрузке сети возможны

Comment: @Mike спасибо! По поводу UDP: в нашей задаче потери не критичны. Думаю, тогда обращу внимание на броадкаст.